# Get Parameter list of a closure dynamically in Groovy

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, groovyshell

I have a Closure defined in a groovy file  that load with the `shell.evaluate()` method.
I need to call this closure in by calling program using the `shell."$closurename".call(arguments`) call.
However to formulate the closure parameters ( argument above) I'd need to now what are the arguments and arguments names that the closure $Closurename accepts. Is there a way of dynamically knowing this in Groovy? I checked in the metaClass.method property but this does not work in my example below.

Below is the example code.

```
        def arguments;
        shell.evaluate(new File("/tmp/myGroovyClosureFile.groovy"))
        testBlock = "myClosureName"
        //Code here to find the parameters for myClosureName and create
        //the arguments variable
        shell."$testBlock".call(arguments)
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jeff mentioned, it seems like groovy when generating code for closures anonymizes somehow the parameter names. However, you can still use reflection to get as much information as you can:

```
def cl = { int a, String b ->
println(a)
println(b)
}

def callMethod = cl.class.methods.find {
    it.name == "call"
}

println callMethod.parameterTypes
println callMethod.parameters.name
```

and outputs:

```
[int, class java.lang.String]
[arg0, arg1]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way of dynamically knowing this in Groovy?

You can't really do it dynamically at runtime.

Comment: In java you can use reflections api to get this information. Is there an equivalent for groovy closures?

Comment: FYI... "In java you can use reflections api to get this information" - If you mean the parameter names that are in the bytecode, that is correct.  If you mean the parameter names that are in the source code, I don't think that is correct unless the class is compiled with debug symbols enabled.